Can't access assets from different directory level problem Laravel 11
Hello I am using laravel 11, I am running into a specific issue for a long time, let me explain my problem with example.
Suppose default laravel directory is like this
/root
  /app
  /bootstrap
  /config
  /database
  /assets/img/packages/img.jpg
  /resources
  /routes
  /...
  /index.php

for security purpose i have moved the public folder out of the main project directory and its structure is like this.
/root
  /main
    /app
    /bootstrap
    /config
    /database
      
    /resources
    /routes
    /...

i am programmatically storing the image in
root/main/public/assets/img/packages/img.jpg
and i want to access it from url like this.
http://web.test/assets/img/packages/img.jpg
but it tries to fetch image from root/assets/img/packages/img.jpg
instead of
root/main/public/assets/img/packages/img.jpg
can anyone assist me with this problem i have been figuring it out from days, Pardon if i am overlooking anything.
I have tried to make custom driver
'custom_assets' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('assets'),
],

The hosting service i am using uses LiteSpeed Web Servers (LSWS) which is similiar to apache but i don't have access to its configuration since i am using shared hosting due to budget constraints.I tried to configure it with .htaccess file but it still throws 403 error. This was the content of the .htaccess file.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Edit: I got the reason that was causing the problem actually i was using vscode to edit the .htaccess file but because of a plugin it was automatically saved in a single line that was causing the issue.
Here how it was getting saved.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

when i used notepad to edit it started working fine.

Did you move everything from root to root/main? And why is it a security issue with the original structure?

@Mr.Kenneth Yes i moved everything except the content of public folder to main folder, Actually the reason for moving it wasn't exactly security, i wasn't able to access it like this https://web.test i had to exactly type https://web.test/public when i uploaded it to the shared hosting server, and i read in an article that it is safer to keep the Laravel installation on a different location.

You needing to access https://web.test/public is because of your apache or nginx setup. . In nginx, you need to setup root pointing to the public folder root /var/www/where-you-uploaded-your-laravel-root-directory/public;

You're right that having public/ appear in the URL is a huge security mistake.  But as pointed out already, it means you have misconfigured your webserver.  The solution is to configure nginx/Apache correctly, not move directories around. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/deployment#server-configuration

i tried to do it with .htacces file but it still throws 403 error.
This was the content of the .htaccess file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] </IfModule>

Add such configuration in your question. not in comments. Specify if you are using nginx/apache+htaccess
